Why does the reply link in comments template scroll to comment position?
I'm building a comments template using wp_list_comments(); and comment_form(); — I'm doing it this way because I want to use different containers depending on whether to not there are already comments on the post.
Here's the whole thing:
<?php 
 // Hide on password protected 
 if(post_password_required()) {
  return;
 }
 $comment_count = get_comments_number();
 if($comment_count > 0): 
?>

 <div class="ca alt" id="comments"> 
  <div class="width">
   <h2 class="comments-title">
   <?php
    printf( _nx( 'Comments on &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo; (1)', 'Comments on &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo; (%1$s)', get_comments_number(), 'comments title' ),
    number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ), get_the_title() );
   ?>
   </h2>
   <?php 
    wp_list_comments(array(
     'style'            => 'div',
     'type'         => 'comment',
     'max_depth'    => 3,
     'per_page' => 12,
    ));
   ?>
  </div> <!-- /width -->
 </div> <!-- /ca -->
 <div class="ca" id="comment-form">
  <div class="width">
   <?php comment_form(); ?>
  </div> <!-- /width -->
 </div> <!-- /ca -->

<?php else: ?>

 <div class="ca alt" id="comment-form">
  <div class="width">
   <?php comment_form(); ?>
  </div> <!-- /width -->
 </div> <!-- /ca -->

<?php endif; ?>

My problem is that although the "reply" link appears under each comment it doesn't work as expected. It simply creates an anchor link to the comment it is under, and scrolls it to the top of the viewport. Example:
<a rel="nofollow" class="comment-reply-link" href="#comment-3" data-commentid="3" data-postid="2679" data-belowelement="comment-3" data-respondelement="respond" data-replyto="Reply to [name]" aria-label="Reply to [name]">Reply</a>

The hover label in the browser for this shows: Go to #comment-3 on this page.
Why is this happening? How can I make it behave as expected?

can you rephrase what you mean by using different containers? If there are no comments to reply to then there are no reply links so the situation where you have no comments and click on reply is literally impossible, can you edit the question and clear that up? It's difficult to understand the rest of the question without that

aside from that, what you're describing implies that you've not added the appropriate reply JS or that you've got a custom comment template that's missing IDs etc. I'd recommend you get comments working the normal way then once that's done and working correctly adjust it towards what you wanted. The standard reply system tries to use JS to move and modify the comment form underneath the comment you're replying to so it's clear what you're replying to

look here at the init function in the core reply JS https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.js

Thanks Tom. I mean that when you load the whole comment form with comments_template() the markup  doesn't allow for the styling I want to achieve, so I'm loading the separate parts within my own markup as you can see above.

You're right that I've not explicitly leveraged any JS at all — I had assumed the functions I am using would cover that. I'll look into the resource you posted.

@TomJNowell The given file is present in my install — I don't know if I need to implement it in some way manually? I've just downloaded the Twenty Ten theme and combed through it but I can't see an example in there of where/how that's been done.

it should be covered in any tutorial on how to add comments to classic themes, here's what I found in a quick search on .org https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/#the-comment-reply-script, and here's twentysixteen: https://github.com/WordPress/twentysixteen/blob/master/functions.php#L273, it should be quite fundamental stuff in any guide on comments

Appreciate the pointers @TomJNowell. Often the hardest part of figuring this stuff out is knowing how to ask the question in order to find the answer. I'll try this.
